# How to move objects diagonally in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I can move my object down and up by changing the `y` variable.
I can move my object left and right by changing the `x` variable.
But how do I move diagonally at the same velocity.
If i just do

```
x += velocity;
y += velocity;
```

it will move about 1.5 times faster.

Is there some kind of equation with `cos` and `sin` to make an object move in a direction it is pointed to?
I would want to be able to change it's direction with `SFML(Simple Fast Multimedia Library)` built in function `setRotation()`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not specific to SFML. It is basic cartesian geometry, which you should learn if caring about graphics!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SFML rotating an object won't affect the direction where it is going. So you have to implement it yourself.

```
x+=vel*sin(angle)
y+=vel*cos(angle)
```

For diagonal moving angle=45 degrees or (45*PI)/180 radians depending which sin/cos library you are using(C/C++ library require radians as argument).

Comment: The formula is correct but it is more correct to say the formula compute the x and y component of velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here doesn't really show you why the transforms are so damn useful. For example, assuming you have a `Vector2f` that represents the distance the object moves over a single 'tick' you can obtain the velocity relative to the rotation of the object. This is most likely more convenient for complicated things.

```
sf::Transform rotation;
rotation.setRotation(getRotation()); 
sf::Vector2f velocity;//This could be (1,0) or (0,1) (or anything else) 
setPosition(getPosition()+rotation.transformPoint(velocity);
```